# What am I missing in PAM configuration for RedHat Apache?

Tags: apache-httpd, pam

I am trying to have PAM to use the hosting system's "passwd" and "shadow" file to authenticate a user who is using the web application.

I am using RedHat 6, Apache is 2.2, module mod_authnz_pam for the Apache.

PAM in apache (`httpd.conf`) is configured as such:

```
<Location />
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "basic_auth"
  AuthBasicProvider PAM
  AuthPAMService httpd
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I created a file named `httpd` in `/etc/pam.d` with the following configuration:

```
auth    required    pam_unix.so
account required    pam_unix.so
session required    pam_unix.so
```

SELinux is enabled. `getenforce` returns "Enforcing". 
I also ran the following

```
setsebool -P allow_httpd_mod_auth_pam 1
```

So I get prompted asking for user credentials when I try to visit the IP address. But when I entered my system credentials, I get the following logs

> unix_chkpwd[29856]: check pass; user unknown
>
> unix_chkpwd[29856]: password check failed for user (username)
>
> localhost httpd: pam_unix(httpd:auth): authentication failure;
> logname= uid=48 euid=48 tty= ruser= rhost=xxx.xx.xx.x  user=username

My user name definitely exists in passwd and shadow file, but somehow PAM is saying it doesn't exist.

What else am I missing?

Comment: I'm no expert in apache/httpd nor pam, but I do know many inter-process problems with apache stem from SELinux. Can you give us the output of 'getenforce` to see if it might be related?

Comment: By "RedHat 6", you mean "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6", right?

Comment: @mattdm to the rescue. :)

Comment: @0xSheepdog I turned off SELinux so I assumed there shouldn't been any security context issues. But for sanity's check I will enable it, restart, then use the setbool command

Comment: Yes, please do. Setting SELinux to permissive mode is great for testing. Not for final state. Good luck! Humor but serious > https://stopdisablingselinux.com/

Comment: Not 100% sure, but you probably need a `password required pam_unix.so` line as well. If it works, let me know and I will add it as an answer.

Comment: Also, if you are not setting up special rules, it might be easier to just include the relevant `system-*` PAM file instead of writing a new PAM file.

Answer (score 0):

Set up `/etc/pam.d/httpd` like this, or similar.

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include    system-auth
account    required   pam_nologin.so
account    include    system-auth
password   include    system-auth
session    optional   pam_keyinit force revoke
session    include    system-auth
session    required   pam_loginuid.so
```

The idea is you're having the pam stack look at the other files instead for trying to attempt to verify the login. `system-auth` is typically called by many other pam services such as `login`, `su`, and `sudo`.